# Entity Left Join to Replace SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

I am accustomed to using SQL left joins to get a list of all available options and determine what items are currently selected.  My table structure would look like this

```
Table MainRecord -- recordId | mainRecordInfo
Table SelectedOptions -- recordId | optionId
Table AvailableOptions -- optionId | optionValue
```

and my query would look like this

```
SELECT optionValue, IIF(optionId IS NULL, 0, 1) AS selected
FROM AvailableOptions AS a
LEFT JOIN SelectedOptions AS s ON s.optionId = a.optionId AND a.recordId = 'TheCurrentRecord'
```

I am trying to replace this with Entity Framework, so I need help with both a model and a query -- they both need corrected.

```
public class MainRecord
{
    public int recordId { get; set; }
    public string mainRecordInfo { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("recordId")]
    public List<SelectedOptions> selectedOptions { get; set; }
}
public class SelectedOptions
{
    public int recordId { get; set; }
    public int optionId { get; set; }
}
public class AvailableOptions
{
    public int optionId { get; set; }
    public string optionValue { get; set; }
}
```

Query

```
IQueryable<AvailableOptions> options = from o in context.AvailableOptions select o;
```

I can get a list of AvailableOptions, but how can I get a list and know which ones are selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of selections and available options is small enough, you can do this in memory:

```
var selected = options.Join(record.selectedOptions, ao => ao.optionId, so => so.optionId, (a, s) => new { Available = a, Selected = s });
```

`selected` will now be a list of objects with `Available` and `Selected` as properties and will only contain those that matched in `optionId` value.

If you only wish to get a pure list of `AvailableOptions` that match, simply chain a `Select` to the join:

```
var selected = options.Join(record.selectedOptions, ao => ao.optionId, so => so.optionId, (a, s) => new { Available = a, Selected = s })
.Select(o => o.Available);
```

Comment: The first recommendation appears to be what I need.

Comment: @user8790030: I stopped using SQL-like style and moved to calling the functions in C# style a long time ago precisely because I found joins to be difficult and annoying... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but it is really good to understand the navigational properties that you get from the model. Here is a query that most likely isn't exactly what you want but that demonstrate it

```
from ao in _db.AvailableOptions
where ao.recordId == "TheCurrentRecord" && ao.SelectedOptions.OptionId == 1
select new
MyPoxo {ao.SelectedOptions.Value ?? 0};
```

so instead of just having o you navigate through the joins that gets specified by the FKs. In this example I would assum AvailableOptions would have a linke to SelectedOptions.

Comment: I need help with the navigational properties.  The recordId is not available in AvailableOptions.  Select new is helpful to me -- I didn't understand that previously.

Comment: I can get the list of SelectedOptions with optionValue, but I don't know how to set the navigational properties to get the complete list of AvailableOptions with selected options designated.

Comment: @user8790030 sometimes it is better to select the other way around, so you navigate "with" the FK. that would give a query like: from sl in selectedvalues where sl.optionid == 1 && sl.AvailableOptions.recordId == "TheCurrentRecord" select sl.Value;